# SVG Clear group<g>

Tags: javascript, svg

Suppose i have an svg element like so

```
<svg id="svgCanvas" class="pan" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <g id="viewport">

      //Filled with an arbitrary amount of lines and cirles - examples below.

     <line x1="632" y1="357.5" x2="682" y2="270.89745962155615" class="line" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128); stroke-width: 1.3px;"></line>

     <circle cx="82.08376766398476" cy="367.0988235405059" r="16.5" stroke="blue" fill="white" class="circle"></circle>

    </g>
</svg>
```

how would i go about clearing everything from the that group, whilst also keeping the group element itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using DOM methods without the need for any framework you could go for:

```
var el = document.getElementById("viewport");
while (el.firstChild) {
    el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Oh brilliant this works a treat - sort of on a side node, say i had a button which is clicked to draw everything on the canvas. Button is clicked everything is draw, button is re-clicked then everything is cleared and drawn again. i know this is off topic i can make a new question.

Comment: Yes, please post a new question providing some code example.

Comment: This doesn't keep the elements!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById("viewport").innerHTML = "";
});
```

Comment: this also works really, well. I can assume this is 'faster/less processing power' than a while loop?

Comment: I never made the speed tests. It is just shortest method I know.

Comment: I just got curious on the performance issue and put together a little test with surprising [results](http://jsperf.com/svg-child-remove): Chrome 41 and FF27 are performing about 20 times faster when using `element.removeChild()` instead of `innerHTML = ""`. IE11, though, is about 2 times faster when removing via `innerHTML = ""`. Maybe someone of you could also run the test to improve the results.

Comment: This doesn't keep the elements!